# Cordova -> face-api-js [Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (null, line 0)

Tags: javascript, cordova, face-api

I have spent the last 4 days trying to resolve this issue. I'm finally at the point that no suggestions online have helped. I'm  trying to build a "simple" cordova app that uses face-api.js for mood/expression detection on a real-time local camera feed. The setup is simple: video using iosrtc cordova plugin and then using face-api-js on a canvas overlay to draw face landmarks..etc.

I receive the following error when using safari console (as i'm testing directly on an ios device).
**[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (null, line 0)
file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6ADC69C6-C6F1-45D9-B609-0C85B3E47C4A/Angel.app/www/null**

[image]

[image]

The strange thing is that it seems that the data image resolves after a second or two. You can see that happening here:

[image]

Notice the images start to resolve as my "interval code" repeats:
[image]

Let's dive into the code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content=" media-src * blob: ; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * blob: http: https: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://*/* https://*/* https://*:* "
    />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no,viewport-fit=cover"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,500,700"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,400italic"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <title>Angel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="app">
      <!--*******************
            local video stream
        ********************-->

      <div class="local-stream" id="local-stream"></div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/faceapi/face-api.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  (async () => {
    let MODEL_URL =
      window.cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/assets/models/";

    let videoContainer = document.getElementById("local-stream");

    var localStream, localVideoEl;
    localVideoEl = document.createElement("video");
    localVideoEl.style.height = "250px";
    localVideoEl.style.width = "250px";
    localVideoEl.setAttribute("autoplay", "autoplay");
    localVideoEl.setAttribute("playsinline", "playsinline");
    localVideoEl.setAttribute("id", "video");
    localVideoEl.setAttribute("class", "local-video");
    videoContainer.appendChild(localVideoEl);

    cordova.plugins.iosrtc.registerGlobals();
    return navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true,
      })
      .then(function (stream) {
        console.log("getUserMedia.stream", stream);
        console.log("getUserMedia.stream.getTracks", stream.getTracks());

        // Note: Expose for debug
        localStream = stream;

        // Attach local stream to video element
        localVideoEl.srcObject = localStream;

        //return localStream;

        (async () => {
          
          await faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri(
            "MYHOSTEDMODELS(THIS WORKS FINE)"
          );
          await faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri(
            "MYHOSTEDMODELS(THIS WORKS FINE)"
          );
          await faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri(
            "MYHOSTEDMODELS(THIS WORKS FINE)"
          );
          await faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri(
            "MYHOSTEDMODELS(THIS WORKS FINE)"
          );

          const video = document.getElementById("video");
          const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video);
          videoContainer.append(canvas);
          const dimensions = {
            width: 250,
            height: 250,
          };

          faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, dimensions);

          setInterval(async () => {
            let detection = await faceapi
              .detectAllFaces(video)
              .withFaceLandmarks()
              .withFaceExpressions()
              .withFaceDescriptors();
            let resizedDimensions = faceapi.resizeResults(
              detection,
              dimensions
            );

            //DRAW ON CAMERA IF YOU WANT.
            canvas.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, 250, 250);
            faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDimensions);
            faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDimensions);
            faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDimensions);
          }, 100);
        })();
      })

      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("getUserMedia.error errrrr", err, err.stack);
      });
  })().then(() => {});
});
```

**PLUGINS (package.json)**

```
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-background-mode": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ipad-multitasking": {},
      "cordova-custom-config": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": {},
      "@globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr": {},
      "cordova-plugin-iosrtc": {
        "MANUAL_INIT_AUDIO_DEVICE": "FALSE"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "ios"
    ]
  },
```

**ONE LAST NOTE: Video plays correctly. It's the face-api that seems to blow the entire thing up. ANY HELP WOULD BE MUCH APPRECIATED!!!!**

Comment: I did not try reproducing the error so just from reading the code and error I would suggest to use `await` everywhere before you set interval, to make sure everything is instantiated, because the `null` value concatenated in the path says that some variable is not set. So try putting `await` on these lines: 

`const video = await document.getElementById("video");`
`const canvas = await faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video);`
`await videoContainer.append(canvas);`
`await faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, dimensions);`

Comment: Do you have an idea where the error is raised in your JS code?  Are those images files present at the begining of the execution or are they generated by the application or the plugin ?  If so, the code requiring those image should wait for the creation (using `await` or `then`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I added await and also tried to add it to the face-api JS, but still no luck.